# Visual Studio 2008 , how to jump a function quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to jump a function quickly when i saw a call of that , in Qt Creator you could simply click on `foo` , and it will jump to the right file , and the right line

`int ret = foo();`

How can i do this in VS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press F12 when the cursor is on the symbol you want to go to (actually depending on your keyboard config).

**[Edit]** The command you have to map is `Edit.GoToDefinition`, if you want to setup something else than F12 **[/Edit]**

Right click and choose "Go to definition"

Or use the [Go To Definition extention](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b) to allow Ctrl+Click to go to definition (I love this extention :p )

Comment: I prefer using the keyboard :)

Comment: using the keyboard is quick when you are typing code, because you probably have your cursor very near what you are looking for. But when you navigating through code, putting the cursor at the right place is most of time more long than ctrl clicking the symbol. But it's a matter of personal feeling ;) there is no universal rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use right click on the function call -> go to definition, or put the curser on the function call and press F12